# Can you do a PHP contact form on a bootstrap page without using divs and form classes?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

i am not running this locally, i am running/debugging the issue live

what i mean is, a lot of the examples ive seen seem to have too much markup in them. i am trying to accomplish implementing a simple contact form, and my PHP seems to run just fine, it displays the alert on submit, but its not sending the email. I am not sure if its due to my PHP, but it seems to compile just fine.

Is there an issue with the way these 2 are wiring up?

HTML snip:

```
<form id="contactForm" class="" role="form" method="post"   action="contactHandler2.php">

     <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="name">

     <input class="input-twin" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-MAIL">

     <input type="tel" class="input-twin" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE">

     <select name="focus" id="contact-focus">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Interested In...</option>
        <option value="v0">Opt1 Inquiry</option>
        <option value="v1">Opt2</option>
        <option value="v2">Opt3</option>
     </select>

     <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Details, Availability, Questions, etc"></textarea>

     <input id="submit" type="submit" value="GO!">

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email1 = "myemail@gmail.com";
$email2 = "myotheremail@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "PT Website Inquiry";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||     !isset($_POST['message'])) {

    died('We apologize, but something weird happened. Please try again.');

}

$name = $_POST['name']; //

$email_from = $_POST['email']; //

$phone = $_POST['phone']; //

$focus = $_POST['focus'];

$message = $_POST['message']; //


$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

 $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($message) < 2) {

 $error_message .= 'The message you entered do not appear to be valid.  <br />';

 }

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

  died($error_message);

 }

$email_message = "Someone submitted our website's contact form, here are the details:\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

 }



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n\n";

$email_message .= "They expressed interest in: ".clean_string($focus)."\n\n";

$email_message .= "Message: \n\n".clean_string($message)."\n\n";


$email_message .= "****************\n
                   DO NOT REPLY\n
                   ****************";


// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email1, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
mail($email2, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


// header('Location: http://allcalrecycling.com');

echo "<script>
alert('Thank you! We will reach out shortly.');
window.location.href='index.html';
</script>";


?>


<?php

 }

?>
```

Comment: if you are running it on localhost then you need to do some more settings (check how to send mail via localhost in php). And if you are running it to some server then mail configuration need to be done on that server. Also apply some error reporting too to check any error occurs or not?(may be your php died silently because of that error)

Comment: @Anant its running on a namecheap server and i have checked and the server is configured with PHP 5.3 ...i thought that was enough for mail() to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors while submitting the form ( php & bootstrap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824729/errors-while-submitting-the-form-php-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosting mail service. You can try this library [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) it easy to configurable send email using `SMTP`

Comment: not doing this locally. server is on namecheap and configured with php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

found the issue. firstly its a shared server so some mail settings were off by default, not sure if i could access them. chat support helped with this. that was all they could do though.

first i created a user email on the server, i guess no default one existed for the login name they gave me.

i also saw i was accidentally setting the headers value with the email from the user form instead of one from the server. so i hardcoded it to the name i created in the admin console, and it started working.